# Timeout issue on while running docker run for onlyoffice document server integration

Tags: docker, fedora, onlyoffice

I'm using fedora 24 workstation. I want to integrate onlyoffice in my local. For onlyoffice integration I followed the steps provided in this link - http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/server/integration-edition/docker/docker-installation.aspx

I'm in middle of the installation and got stuck while running below comment in my terminal

```
sudo docker run -i -t -d -p 80:80 onlyoffice/documentserver-integration
```

It's starting downloading the file but at the end it's stopping and showing some tcp timeout error like image[image]

I ran the command couple of times same issue I'm facing. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not onlyoffice related problem per-se. Seems you have some kind of network issues while accessing hub.docker.com. Could you recheck your network connection, maybe reboot your server.

Comment: Thanks for you response. It's installed now